# Worona - Internet connection is available, but cannot connect to website

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I'm using Worona plugin to transform my wordpress website to an Android app. I did all the steps required for this to work but it keeps showing me this error :

```
Internet connection is available, but cannot connect to: 'http://serverip/blogname/'. Please check your WordPress site configuration.
```

I installed and activated both **Worona** and **JSON REST API** plugins.
http://serverip/blogname/wp-json/posts is showing all of my posts, so the JSON api is working fine.
Any help would be appreciated.

Using `Wordpress 3.9.3` `Worona 0.7` `JSON REST API 1.1.1`

Comment: `serverip` ? Please elaborate. Where is that server? Where is the client?

Comment: We solved the issue with @Mehdiway by mail. There was a bug in the Worona App code, but it has been fixed already :)